# Variable as value of array (array[variable])

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function, which calls a value out of a defined array:

```
var categories = [];
categories[caller1] = "asasd";
categories[caller2] = "asasd";
categories[caller3] = "asasd";

function getNewItem(caller){
    $("#"+categories[caller]).show();
}
```

So the basic problem is, that this doesn't work:

```
function(VARIABLE){
    $("#"+ categories[VARIABLE]).show();
}
```

This code is reduced to the minimum to show the problem.

Comment: _reduced to the minimum_ to the minimum of a syntax error?

Comment: Apart from the missing "`+`" after `"#"`, and the duplicate `caller2` in the `categories`, what exactly is the problem / solution that you need?

Comment: Yeah i really messed up with copy and paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to see what caller1, caller2, and caller3 are defined as. I'm assuming, as I'm sure we all are, that they are integers. As such, it would look something like this:

```
var caller1 = 0
  , caller2 = 1
  , caller3 = 2
;//var

var categories = [];
categories[caller1] = "asasd";
categories[caller2] = "asasd";
categories[caller3] = "asasd";

function getNewItem(caller){ $("#" + categories[caller]).show() }
```

But my other assumption is that they might be strings, in which case you're doing this all wrong. Use an object instead of an array.

```
var caller1 = 'Gary'
  , caller2 = 'John'
  , caller3 = 'Paul'
;//var

var categories = {};
categories[caller1] = "asasd";
categories[caller2] = "asasd";
categories[caller3] = "asasd";

function getNewItem(caller){ $("#" + categories[caller]).show() }
```

But this could even be extended to functions and numbers as well:

```
var caller1 = function(){ return 'blah' }
  , caller2 = 8
  , caller3 = 'aString'
;//var

var categories = {};
categories[caller1] = "asasd";
categories[caller2] = "asasd";
categories[caller3] = "asasd";

function getNewItem(caller){ $("#" + categories[caller]).show() }
```

Comment: no they are not. my problem is that i have to call the caller(?) with the function

Comment: Check out my last example. If caller is a function, you can index the object using the function pointer as a key, just like I did. Your problem is probably how you're passing in the function. You have to do it using the name of the function. The function can not be anonymous, even if you type it exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate:

```
"#" + categories[caller]
  --^--
```

Also you have an array but you should be using an object:

```
var categories = {};
categories.caller1 = 'asd';
$("#"+ categories.caller1).show();
```

Plus you have some serious syntax errors, but try the code above it should work.